# How difficult are SS7 hacks?

Tags: sms, ss7

Out of band communication via SMS has recently been shunned due to SS7 hacks. How likely are these to become more prevalent? I saw this question:

[Should 2FA over SMS be considered insecure in the wake of recent SS7 attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158770/should-2fa-over-sms-be-considered-insecure-in-the-wake-of-recent-ss7-attacks)

But nothing I have seen shows how easy / difficult they are to perform? And how common they are?

Comment: I think it is detailed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127284/is-ss7-a-threat-any-more?rq=1

Comment: if you search for the tag `ss7` you will get a lot of info